# MySQL Regular expressions: How to match digits in the string with \d?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a column `release_date` which stores date in a string format(Not in DATETIME format. Because they can be sometime any other string literals).

I want to find all the records based on given month and year but with any date.

Tried following but did not work for me,

```
> Post.find(:all, :conditions => ["release_date RLIKE ? AND deleted_at is null", "^\d{2}-01-2016"])
```

When I try same thing with following by giving direct date, it works fine.

```
> Post.find(:all, :conditions => ["release_date RLIKE ? AND deleted_at is null", "09-01-2016"])
```

Note:- I am using `Ruby On Rails 2` and `MySQL`

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I suggest updating your rails ASAP! At least to rails 4..

Comment: @RaVeN - We are working on it. But I guess my question is more related to `MySQL`. Any ideas on actual question would save me. Nice suggestion though :)

Comment: I think you need to use the mysql regexp function to mark the string you're passing as a regex: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: Thanks @chris85 It worked. I generally use `\d` for digit matching. But I wonder why it is not working in this scenario. It would be great if you have any more information on it and make it as answer. I'm happy to accept.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\d` is not supported by mysql/posix. Use a character class `[0-9]` and it should work. Alternatively you could use the posix character class for numbers `[:digit:]`.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b952d/3

http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html